# VSCode: The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (posix_spawnp failed.)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, launch

I get the mentioned error above.

I am on MAC

I tried to restart the VSCode, but I can't run terminal

I used Run and Debug  with custom lunch.json to start my code

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and now it works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This was raised in issue ticket [Integrated terminal won't launch
#181521](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181521). Someone there said that the issue went away after installed security update 13.3.1(a) and then restarting their machine.

Comment: I did not made any changes before getting this error.
I ran many test and maybe this is what caused this issue.